# how to open div with selection option using radio button

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hello Am using the following script to open div. but am not able to view any result based on my request

my script as follows:

```
<script>
    function showfield(name) {
        if(name=='Others') {
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<input type="text" name="other" />';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='hai';
        }
    }
</script>
```

My HTML Program as follows:

```
<form id='form-id'>
    <input id='watch-me' name='test' type='radio' value="a" />Show Div
    <br />
    <input name='test' type='radio' onClick="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" value="Others" />
    <br />
    <input name='test' type='radio' value="c" />
</form>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in the input call function:

```
 <input name='test' type='radio' onClick="showfield(this.value)" value="Others" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```js
function showfield(name){
  if(name=='Others'){
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<input type="text" name="other" />';
  }else{
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='hai';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='form-id'>
  <input id='watch-me' name='test' type='radio' onClick="showfield(this.value);" value="a" />Show Div
  <br />
  <input name='test' type='radio' onClick="showfield(this.value);" value="Others" />
  <br />
  <input name='test' type='radio' onClick="showfield(this.value);" value="c" />
</form>

<div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick` event was off, it needed an ending parenthesis and just `this.value`.

```
<input name='test' type='radio' onClick="showfield(this.value)" value="Others" />
```

Here's a working JSBin with the refactored JavaScript: http://jsbin.com/mehulov/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Note that each input should have an onClick event too, I added it in the JSBin demo.